# Confusion about a form $<,>$ on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ being non-degenerate on a subspace $W$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, inner-products

I'm currently going through Artin's Abstract Algebra book, and I'm a bit confused about the following:

He says that a form $<,>$ on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ is **non-degenerate** if its nullspace is $\{0\}$.

Now, here is my question:

> There are two potential meanings for the notation $W^\perp$:
>
> 1. $W^\perp$ may denote the orthogonal space to $W$. That is:
>    $$W^\perp = \{v \in V: <v,w> = 0 \space \text{for all}\space  w \in W \}$$
> 2. $W^\perp$ may denote the nullspace of the restriction $<,>|_W$. That is:
>    $$W^\perp = \{v \in W: <v,w> = 0 \space \text{for all} \space w \in W \}$$
>
> When we say that a form $<,>$ on $V$ is non-degenerate on a subspace $W$, we are trying to say that $W^\perp = \{0\}$, but which interpretation of $W^\perp$ is normally meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one:$$W^\perp=\left\{v\in W\,\middle|\,(\forall w\in W):\langle v,w\rangle=0\right\}.$$